# Convert between spark.SQL DataFrame and pandas DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

Is that possible to

convert from 

to 
pd.DataFrame

under %pyspark environment ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try:

```
spark_df.toPandas()
```

> toPandas()
>
> ```
> Returns the contents of this DataFrame as Pandas pandas.DataFrame.
>
> This is only available if Pandas is installed and available.
> ```

And if you want the oposite:

```
spark_df = createDataFrame(pandas_df)
```

Comment: This is not working if the pandas dataframe is very very big.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: java heap out of memory error.

Comment: The heap for the driver maybe is too low for the size of the DataFrame and is not allowed to store in the JVM memory Try to change the driver memory size.

Comment: Also remember that Spark Dataframe uses RDD which is basically a distributed dataset spread across all the nodes.  So a big data can be processed without issues. However when you convert this big data set into a Pandas dataframe, it will most likely run out of memory as Pandas dataframe is not distributed like the spark one and uses only the driver node's memory and not all the other available nodes.

Comment: I am getting this error going from a valid 364-row by 9-column Pandas dataframe to a pyspark one:
`TypeError: field Total Rain Flag: Can not merge type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.DoubleType'> and <class 'pyspark.sql.types.StringType'>`