# How do I create a seaborn line plot for PySpark dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame with three columns and I am trying to do a line plot using Seaborn library but it throws me an error saying that `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'get'`. Here is my test data frame

```
Age variable    value
31  Overall 69.76751118
31  Potential   69.76751118
31  Growth  0
34  Overall 68.91176471
34  Potential   68.91176471
34  Growth  0
28  Overall 69.05803996
28  Potential   69.05803996
28  Growth  0.24643197
```

This is what I am trying to do using the seaborn line plot after reading in the csv file

```
test = spark.read.csv("test.csv", inferSchema=True, header=True)
sns.lineplot(x = "Age", y = "value", hue = "variable", data = test)
```

And the error that I get is this

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'get'
```

However when I convert the data frame to Pandas data frame and use exactly the same seaborn code it works

```
test_df = test.toPandas()
sns.lineplot(x = "Age", y = "value", hue = "variable", data = test_df)
```

[image]

Am I doing anything wrong with Spark Data frames.

Comment: Not possible- you need to [convert to a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41826553/convert-between-spark-sql-dataframe-and-pandas-dataframe) first, which is going to be expensive.

Comment: Is there an alternative other than converting to Pandas Dataframe?

Comment: Any solution will require the data to be on your local machine, which involves a `collect` type operation.

Comment: Ah I see. I will give it a try and see if that works. Thanks..

Answer (score 10):

A spark dataframe and a pandas dataframe, despite sharing a lot of the same functionalities, differ on where and how they allocate data.

This step is correct:

```
test_df = test.toPandas()
```

You will always need to collect the data before you can use it to plot with seaborn (or even matplotlib)

Comment: Be very careful while doing this as this will pull all the data to driver node. On large dataset it might cause OOM.

Comment: @Nandeesh Exactly! This makes distributed spark paradigm pointless...what's the solution?

Comment: @PabloBoswell, the problem is that the data reduction generally is done inside the plotting library. So the solution is, instead of downloading millions of rows of data and plotting a histogram, you do the data reduction in spark and create the exactly same view using a bar plot and downloading only 10 rows of data from spark. Despite simple, I never found a python package dedicated to it, ready for histograms, density, etc.